# Query multiple metrics in one Prometheus HTTP Call

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to make one http call to Prometheus server and get the following:

- Multiple metrics
- Calculate rate for all metrics within last 30 seconds

I have the following query which works, it requests the results of multiple prometheus metrics in one call for last 30 seconds. I`m just not sure how to extend this query to also calculate the rate for all these metrics. Can anyone help?

```
/api/v1/query?query={__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3",service=~"testservice"}[30s]
```

I want to do something like

```
    /api/v1/query?query={rate(__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3",service=~"testservice"}[30s])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `rate` before the labels. This should work:

```
/api/v1/query?query=rate({__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3",service=~"testservice"}[30s])
```

Note that you must have at least one datapoint in the 30s period for each of the metrics.

Comment: I tried that and I get this error.     "error": "vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset"

Comment: @Eats same error I also got, what changes you made it to get success?

Comment: @codeSeeker using functions such as `rate` removes the metric names. This is the only difference between some of your metrics. Potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944000/how-to-avoid-vector-cannot-contain-metrics-with-the-same-labelset-error-when-p