# How to avoid "vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset" error when plotting rate() from several metrics (same labelset, different names)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

In Prometheus sometimes we need to plot several metrics at onces (say, having name, fitting the same regex) like that PromQL query:

```
{name=~"camel_proxy.*count"}
```

and it works fine, the same labelset lines are plotted with the different names.

When we want to plot the rate() of them, we face the error from the title:

```
rate({name=~"camel_proxy.*count"}[5m])
```

So, the way here is to make labelset not the same, and to move the `__name__` to some label, making each labelset to be unique:

```
rate(label_replace({name=~"camel_proxy.*count"},"name_label","$1","name", "(.+)")[5m])
```

But we are still getting the error like

```
1:90: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors"
```

How to avoid it and plot the rates correctly?

Comment: I found I had to use `__name__` instead of `name` in the query that Ilya shared here - both in the metric-selector at the start, and also in the `label_replace` function as follows: ```label_replace({__name__=~"camel_proxy.*count"},"name_label","$1","__name__", "(.+)")``` (I tried to update the question itself with an edit, but the edit-queue on Stack Overflow was full )

Comment: This doesn't work for me I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `label_replace()` inside `rate()` triggers [subquery processing](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/), which may return unexpected results, since the `rate()` starts working with **calculated** samples returned from `label_replace()` instead of raw samples stored in the database.

[MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) at VictoriaMetrics (this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on) provides more elegant solution for `vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` error - `keep_metric_names` modifier. Just put this modifier after the function, which strips metric names, in order to instruct it to keep metric names:

```
rate({name=~"camel_proxy.*count"}[5m]) keep_metric_names
```

This solution avoids triggering `subquery processing`, so the `rate()` function continues working on raw samples stored in the database.

Answer (score 10):

The PromQL query here should be:

```
rate(label_replace({name=~"camel_proxy.*count"},"name_label","$1","name", "(.+)")[5m:])
```

Please note: you need to add colon `:`, in `5m:` instead of `5m`