# Parsing a multi valued custom variable in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Following is the code snippet

```
max_over_time(PrometheusMetric_$Region{job="JOBNAME"}[1m])
```

which is taking a custom variable made in Grafana named Region which can take values from {North_Europe, East_US, Southeast_Asia}. I want that while viewing metrics on Grafana, we have the option to select 2 or more regions at a time to view the plots collectively.
When I select 2 or more regions, the following error is thrown.
`bad_data: 1:89: parse error: unexpected character: '|'`

What is the code fix suggested. Also Region here is not a prometheus label, so we cannot keep it inside curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a variable with values `1`, `2` and `3` selected. This is how it is expanded, if used in a query:

```
"$myvar" -> "(1|2|3)"
```

This is where the `unexpected character: '|'` comes from.

To use a multi-value variable inside a query you need to use the regex-match operator: `=~`, e.g.

```
foo=~"(1|2|3)"
```

Fortunately for you, metric name is also a label, so you may try something like this:

```
max_over_time({__name__=~"PrometheusMetric_$Region", job="JOBNAME"}[1m])
```

Comment: Getting the following error - execution: vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset

Comment: @Adriraj This is another problem and it has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944000/how-to-avoid-vector-cannot-contain-metrics-with-the-same-labelset-error-when-p

Comment: The suggested fixes dont work for me. Can you suggest any other way or a way to make this work?