# Visualize Multiple Prometheus query in one table

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-transform

I wanted to Visualize two Prometheus Query in Grafana in one table as a raw list. the two queries have the same fields. the queries are `increase(message_recieved[$_range])` and
`increase(message_sent[$_range])`

When I tried to use transformation merge it visualized them in one raw and two extra columns "value A" and "value B". but I wanted it to be visualized in raws.

The table looks like this

| namespace | pod | service | Value #A | Value #B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mkn | mkn_1875 | jck | 29 | 36 |

I wanted to look like this

| type | pod | service | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| recived | mkn_1875 | jck | 29 |
| sent | mkn_1875 | jck | 36 |

Answer (score 0):

You may (!?) be able to leverage the fact that Prometheus implements metric (!) names as a special label name `__name__`.

Your metrics `message_received` (sic.) and `message_sent` are thus both accessible through the single query:

```
{__name__=~"message_(received|sent)"}
```

However, this yields 2 metrics with the same labels when name (`__name__`) is removed by `increase`.

You can use [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) to create a synthetic label (in my example) `foo` to represent the difference in the label names (`(received|sent)`):

```
label_replace(
  {__name__=~"message_(received|sent)"},
  "foo",
  "$1",
  "message_(received|sent)"
)
```

But then you can't simply wrap that query with `increase()`.

For explanations see:

- Both answers in question [68944000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944000)
- Both answers in question [61169517](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169517)

So, given the **caveats** explained in those answers, you may (I don't use Grafana and so don't know whether this is supported) but you need `$_range:` (the appended colon makes this a subquery) instead of `$_range`:

```
increase(
  label_replace(
    {__name__=~"message_(received|sent)"},
    "foo",
    "$1",
    "message_(received|sent)"
  )[$_range:]
)
```